# Entity print broken when updating to PHP8.1

Tags: 9

I've updated my drupal environment **php 7.4** to **php 8.1.18**. i've enable some extensions, but I have this error when i try to download a PDF

```
Error : Typed property DOMDocument::$documentElement must not be accessed before initialization in Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\DOMTreeBuilder->startTag() (/var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/DOMTreeBuilder.php line 275)

#0 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/Tokenizer.php(399): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\DOMTreeBuilder->startTag()
#1 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/Tokenizer.php(141): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\Tokenizer->tagName()
#2 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5/Parser/Tokenizer.php(82): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\Tokenizer->consumeData()
#3 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5.php(161): Masterminds\HTML5\Parser\Tokenizer->parse()
#4 /var/www/myproject/vendor/masterminds/html5/src/HTML5.php(89): Masterminds\HTML5->parse()
#5 /var/www/myproject/vendor/dompdf/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php(478): Masterminds\HTML5->loadHTML()
#6 /var/www/myproject/web/modules/contrib/entity_print/src/Plugin/EntityPrint/PrintEngine/DomPdf.php(207): Dompdf\Dompdf->loadHtml()
```

the extensions are the same than PHP7.4

[image]

EDIT :

By digging, I've found that this on
[image]

is producing this on php7

[image]

but this in php8 (going through the same functions)...

[image]

The `nodeName` is just `name` in php 8 (and so on). Do I have to change another thing in my server to update the \DOMImplementation() ?

EDIT 2 :

i've remade the delivry of my package to another server (so php7.4 to php8.1.13), same result. It only works into my docker container, not my client server. Here's my procedure :

```
apt install php8.1-fpm php8.1-xml php8.1-mysql php8.1-gd php8.1-cli php8.1-common php8.1-mbstring php8.1-opcache php8.1-readline php8.1-curl php8.1-bcmath php8.1-zip

    I. edit ini file : /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini

extension=gd
extension=zip
extension=dom
extension=pdo_mysql
extension=mbstring

II. Restart PHP/Nginx
sudo systemctl restart php8.1-fpm
sudo systemctl restart nginx
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php8.1
```

Comment: What version of the module is installed?

Comment: Version 2.11 with drupal 9

Comment: If you can't upgrade to PHP 8.2 for whatever reason, you may also try the latest version of PHP 8.1.*, i.e. 8.1.19 and it upgrading to it should be enough for fixing this issue. Also, as pointed in this comment: https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php/issues/220#issuecomment-1580998305 - maybe a conflict of the extensions is happening?

Comment: I removed the extension and it solved it

Answer (score 0):

This is not entity_print related, but to it's dependencies, you should use PHP 8.2.x, see https://github.com/Masterminds/html5-php/issues/220

Comment: Works fine on php8.1 on my docker container...

Comment: Indeed, works with PHP8.2, but Drupal 9 doesn't fully support PHP8.2...